# How to make scrolling to target smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set up an comment button that is link to comment section of the page, it's like this
Comments

Demo on this page  http://stramaxon.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-remove-shadows-from-pictures-in.html#disqus_thread

When you click it, you will be taken to the comments section, now i want the scrolling to be smooth, i know it is possible but can't find the key to achieve it. I am sure intelligent web designers in Stackoverflow will help me out.

I want it to be like this, check this page http://www.labnol.org/internet/bing-background-for-google-homepage/21303/

Scroll down and you will see a back to top button, it's so smooth i love it and want something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#topBtn").click(scrollToTop);

function scrollToTop()
{
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
}
```

should work

EDIT: that's for a non href, when you wanna use it on a href you should to it like this

```
function scrollToTop()
{
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
    return false;
}
```